# Java Incompatible Types Error Arraylists

Tags: java, bluej

I'm using BlueJ as an IDE and whenever I try to compile this Java code it gives me an error: `incompatible types` highlighting the brackets of:

```
s.getCourtSportArrayList()
```

Why this is happening?

```
public void showCourtBookings()
{
 for(Sport s : sportList)
 {
   for(Court c : s.getCourtSportArrayList() )
   {
     System.out.println("Court: " + c.getCourt);
     int i;
     i=1;
     for(Booking b : c.getBookings())
     {  
         System.out.println("Booking: " + i + "Start Time: " + b.getTimeStart() + "End Time :" + b.getEndTime());
         i = i + 1;
     }
   }
 }  
}
```

This is a class `Club`, it contains two ArrayLists;

```
private ArrayList<Member> MemberList;
private ArrayList<Sport> sportList;
```

The `Sport` class has the following ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<Court> CourtList = new ArrayList<Court>();
```

The `Court` class has these ArrayLists:

```
private ArrayList<Booking> listBooking;
```

Hopefully you can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Edit: this is the code,

```
public ArrayList getCourtSportArrayList()
{
  return CourtList;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `c.getCourt` be `c.getCourt()`?

Comment: What is the code of getCourtSportArrayList()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getCourtSportArrayList()` seems to be a method of your Sport class. This method needs to return a `List<Court>` which it apparently does not right now.

in result the method should look like this:

```
public List<Court> getCourtSportArrayList()
{
   return CourtList;
}
```

Side note: You should specify the generic Type `List<Court>` instead of `ArrayList<Court>` unless you use specific implementation details of ArrayList.

Comment: It does though... or did I write it incorrectly?
        public ArrayList getCourtSportArrayList()
   {
       return CourtList;
    }

Comment: Java does not magically add getter and setter methods to your private member objects like private ArrayList<Court> CourtList. You need to code this explicitly.

Comment: You need to specify the type! ```public List<Court> getCourtSportArrayList() { return CourtList; }```

Comment: I've had to find a workaround for using ArrayLists since Iv'e been declaring them incorrectly in the method signatures this entire time. Thankyou :)